# How to iterate through a VB.net Dictionary Collection

Tags: vb.net

When I iterate through this collection, they key and Province are not in sync. Can someone tell me why ?

```
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    Dim Country As Dictionary(Of String, Province)

    Country = Module1.CreateCountry

    Dim s As String

    s = ""

    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Province) In Country
        s = s + kvp.Key + "; " + kvp.Value.ProvName + "; " + kvp.Value.Region + "; " + kvp.Value.Population + vbCrLf
    Next

    TextBox4.Text = s

End Sub
```

Module Module1

```
Module Module1

    Public provinces As CollectionBase


    Function CreateCountry() As Dictionary(Of String, Province)

        Dim Country As New Dictionary(Of String, Province)

        Dim Prov As Province
        Prov = New Province

        With Prov
            .Abbrv = "Qc"
            .ProvName = "Quebec"
            .Population = "7 500 000"
            .Region = "East"
        End With
        Country.Add(Prov.Abbrv, Prov)


        With Prov
            .Abbrv = "BC"
            .ProvName = "British Columbia"
            .Population = "4 500 000"
            .Region = "West"
        End With
        Country.Add(Prov.Abbrv, Prov)

        With Prov
            .Abbrv = "AB"
           .ProvName = "Alberta"
            .Population = "5 500 000"
            .Region = "Prairies"
        End With
        Country.Add(Prov.Abbrv, Prov)

        With Prov
            .Abbrv = "NS"
            .ProvName = "Nova Scotia"
            .Population = "2 000 000"
            .Region = "Maritimes"
        End With
        Country.Add(Prov.Abbrv, Prov)

        Return Country

    End Function
End Module
```

Public Class Province

```
Public Class Province

    Public Property Abbrv As String
    Public Property ProvName As String
    Public Property Population As String
    Public Property Region As String

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in the dictionary you add a pointer-reference of `Province`.

In your case you don't create a new instance of `Province` but each time you change the properties of the same instance. So when you are done the instance of `Province` keeps the last values of properties.

For each add, create `Country.Add` a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    ' use a List instead of a Dictionary
    Dim Country As New List(Of Province)

    ' this code adds 4 Province objects to  Country List
    Country.Add(New Province() With {.Abbrv = "Qc", .Population = "7500000", .ProvName = "Quebec", .Region = "East"})
    Country.Add(New Province() With {.Abbrv = "BC", .Population = "4500000", .ProvName = "British Columbia", .Region = "West"})
    Country.Add(New Province() With {.Abbrv = "AB", .Population = "5500000", .ProvName = "Alberta", .Region = "Prairies"})
    Country.Add(New Province() With {.Abbrv = "NS", .Population = "2000000", .ProvName = "Nova Scotia", .Region = "Maritimes"})

    ' now you can select any one of the 4 elements in the  Country List like so....
    Dim prov As Province = (From c In Country Where c.Abbrv = "AB" Select c).FirstOrDefault

End Sub

End Module

Public Class Province

Public Property Abbrv As String
Public Property ProvName As String
Public Property Population As String
Public Property Region As String

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a grasp of *reference types* in order to understand and fix the problem.

Long story short, you want *four* distinct `Province` instances in your dictionary, all with different property values - but you only ever create one (`Prov = New Province`), and then keep mutating that same instance and re-adding it to the dictionary. Naturally, what you end up with is a dictionary with 4 `KeyValuePair`s where the `Value`s all point to the same `Province` instance.

The solution is to `New` up a `Province` instance before setting its property values and adding it to the dictionary, like so:

```
Function CreateCountry() As Dictionary(Of String, Province)

    Dim Country As New Dictionary(Of String, Province)

    Dim Prov As Province
    Prov = New Province ' Prov now points to instance #1.

    With Prov
        .Abbrv = "Qc"
        .ProvName = "Quebec"
        .Population = "7 500 000"
        .Region = "East"
    End With
    Country.Add(Prov.Abbrv, Prov)

    Prov = New Province ' Added. Prov now points to instance #2.

    With Prov
        .Abbrv = "BC"
        .ProvName = "British Columbia"
        .Population = "4 500 000"
        .Region = "West"
    End With
    Country.Add(Prov.Abbrv, Prov)

    Prov = New Province ' Added. Prov now points to instance #3.

    With Prov
        .Abbrv = "AB"
       .ProvName = "Alberta"
        .Population = "5 500 000"
        .Region = "Prairies"
    End With
    Country.Add(Prov.Abbrv, Prov)

    ' Alternative syntax. Prov will point to instance #4.
    Prov = New Province With {
        .Abbrv = "NS",
        .ProvName = "Nova Scotia",
        .Population = "2 000 000",
        .Region = "Maritimes"
    }
    Country.Add(Prov.Abbrv, Prov)

    Return Country

End Function
```

*Note the alternative initialization syntax for the last `Prov` instance.*